# Are the following Mathematica codes correct for solving wave equation PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

I wanna solve the following PDE of wave equation using Mathematica.

$u_{tt}=u_{xx}$

$0<x<\pi  ,   t>0$

Initial Conditions:

$\begin{cases}u(x,0)=sin(x) \\u_{t}(x,0)=1\end{cases}$

Boundary Conditions:

$\begin{cases}u(0,t)+u_{x}(0,t)=1\\u(\pi,t)+u_{x}(\pi,t)=-1\end{cases}$

- I know the boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.

Are the following codes correct?

```
weqn = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = {u[x, 0] == Sin[x],Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 1 };
bc = {u[0, t] + Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 1, 
   u[Pi, t] + Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == -1};
sol = NDSolve[{weqn, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Comment: Yes! Apparently it looks fine.

Comment: @zhk In this case, the solution happens to be correct, but it's no more than a coincidence. Just change `u[0, t] + Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 1` to e.g. `u[0, t] + Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 100`, you'll find the solution doesn't change at all. To make the solution always correct, option like `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 20}}` is necessary. One can also turn to `FiniteElement` method, of course. Please check the linked question for more information.

Comment: @xzczd Thx for pointing that out.

Comment: Are the b.c. correct? Only for `bc = {u[0, t] - Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 1 , 
   u[Pi, t] + Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == -1};` I get finite symmetric periodic solution!

Comment: @xzczd here the solution of a hyperbolic type equation is discussed, and in your example, a solution has been given of a parabolic type equation. How can these problems be duplicates?

Comment: @alex There's no doubt it's a duplicate. Though the equations are different, the root of both problems is the way `NDSolve` treats inconsistent i.c. and b.c., and as mentioned in my last comment, the solution is to adjust `DifferentiateBoundaryConditions` option or turn to `FiniteElement` method, which is the same as mentioned in the linked question.

Comment: @xzczd For methodical purposes, a solution must be given. Other users, such as mathematicians, may not understand what the connection is between the two problems.

Comment: @Alex Well, I think my first comment already forms a simple answer. Let's wait for OP's reply, if OP thinks the given solution and the linked question are too hard to understand, we can reopen this one.